# What is the meaning of "overarch" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I consulted the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overarch) and saw the definitions of overarch:

> ***verb (used with object)***
>
> 1. to span with or like an arch: A new bridge overarches the river.
>
> ***verb (used without object)***
>
> 1. to form an arch over something: a cerulean sky overarching in the early twilight.

In this [sentence](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tech-decision-maker/the-benefits-of-a-successful-strategic-bi-implementation/),

> In this blog, I intend to identify and discuss the ***overarching***
>   benefits derived from successful Strategic BI implementation.

what is the meaning of ***overarching***? Does it mean overflowing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look under **overarching**, where the dictionary definition says:

> encompassing or overshadowing everything: *The community's overarching needs are more jobs and better housing.*

Sometimes a different form of the word has only slightly-related meanings to the root.